# What do you call a person who sacrifices another when they could have chosen not to?

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns, philosophy

> “He may have hurt you in the past, but in this situation, he was completely innocent. You and Scott preyed upon an innocent bystander.”
>
> Anna sweated. “It’s, um… a classic case of the Trolley Problem. You know, run over five people or pull the lever to divert the track and run over one person.”
>
> “No, it’s not,” Merrick argued, crossing his arms and leaning back in his chair. “Are you trying to call yourself a utilitarian? A person who chooses to save the many while sacrificing the few? You didn't have to give him up to the authorities. Think about it. What would've ended up differently if you hadn't?"

In this story, Scott sacrificed his best friend, getting him put in prison for life. He regrets it now, but the damage has already been done. However, there is one person, the main character Anna, who *does* have the ability to save him but has chosen not to since the character in jail has hurt her in the past.

Now, whenever I reference this person being sacrificed by his friend, I have a dilemma of sorts. I have heard about the case of the "Trolley Problem," where you either run over a group of people or divert the track and end up only running over one. However, in this case, there only was one person, and it was either run over him or divert the track and run over nobody. Now this character has a vendetta against both the person who got him put in jail and the person who refused to save him.

People who choose to sacrifice one person versus, say, three people are called "utilitarians". However, what would you call a person who chooses to sacrifice somebody when they could've chosen not to?

Comment: I'm not sure "sacrifice" is the right way to view this. Sacrifice implies Anna gets some benefit out of the situation but instead she seems to just watch ill come of him out of spite. I can't think of a particular word though.

Comment: @Weather Vane I may be wrong, but I thought schadenfreude is just when someone enjoys seeing others suffer, particularly if they had no part in it, ie. if a storm wipes out someone (who they hate)'s house.
Still, I was looking for a name for the person, not the concept

Comment: So what you're asking is how to classify a person who, without being responsible for whatever causes the harm, deliberately chooses to let it go ahead rather than avert it? It's certainly a variation of the Trolley Problem of ethical dilemma, and may be suitable for the [philosophy.se] Stack.

Comment: Am I correct that you're referring to someone who stands by and lets others be harmed, instead of doing anything to prevent it? Or are you referring to someone who turns others over to the authorities for no reason?

Answer (score 1):

Good one!

Well, I'm pretty sure the word you're looking for is not **[pragmatist](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/pragmatist)**, since a pragmatist can be a decent person; many are.

A person who sets someone up "just in case" - or some such **[dick move](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=dick%20move)** - would be called a **[scoundrel](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/scoundrel)**, a word that in today's vernacular has been replaced by **[asshole](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/asshole)**. Some **[social darwinists](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Social_Darwinism)** are like that.

Comment: Well, my story's strictly family friendly vocabulary wouldn't support such a word, so maybe it would be better in that case to just call her a "jerk" ^ワ^

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't realize we were talking about a woman. You're right: the feminine equivalent of any of the above (an exact one, too, starts with a "c") isn't "family friendly."

Comment: Last I checked, women have buttholes, too, but I get what you're saying XD